# WPF-like layout in HTML5 /CSS3

Tags: css, html

How can I achieve the equivalent of:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="300">
  <RowDefinition Height="*">
  <RowDefinition Height="100">
```

whe the row with height * fills the remaining screen space after the top and bottom rows have taken their 400px?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using div(s)

```
<div class="upperSection">

</div>

<div class="content">

</div>


<div class="lowerSection">

</div>
```

and Css:

```
.upperSection
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;
}

.content
{
  position:absolute;
  top:300px;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.lowerSection
{
  position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 height:100px;
 width:100%;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. The content box's height is the same height as the screen. Not the gab between upper and lower. Does this mean you'd need javascript to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem:

```
.upperSection
{    
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:300px;
    width:100%;

}

.content
{  
  position:absolute;   
  left:0;
  top:300px;
  bottom:100px;  
  width:100%;



}

.lowerSection
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 height:100px;
 width:100%;


}
```

Cheers.